# Keep an integer within bounds?

Tags: c#

To keep an integer within certain bounds, currently I'm doing:

```
frame.X = frame.X <= 0 ? 0 : frame.X;
frame.X = frame.X + frame.Width > Image.Width ? Image.Width - frame.Width : frame.X;

frame.Y = frame.Y <= 0 ? 0 : frame.Y;
frame.Y = frame.Y + frame.Height > Image.Height ? Image.Height - frame.Height : frame.Y;
```

Is there a cleaner way for bound checking?

Comment: It's confusing to look at.  Does that help answer your question?  I don't agree with the downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compactness (although not performance) you could consider something like this:

```
frame.X = Math.Min(Image.Width - frame.Width, Math.Max(0, frame.X));
frame.Y = Math.Min(Image.Height - frame.Height, Math.Max(0, frame.Y));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aim at a structural approach, you can use the extension methods

```
public static class IComparableExtensions
{

    public static T Min<T>(this T a, T b) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b) < 0 ? a : b;
    }

    public static T Max<T>(this T a, T b) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return a.CompareTo(b) > 0 ? a : b;
    }

    public static T Clip<T>(this T a, T Min, T Max) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return a.Max(Min).Min(Max);
    }
}
```

to factor out the catual checking.